# Pound symbol (£) showing as '?' in utf-8 encoded string

Tags: java, android, utf-8, textview, inputstream

I'm reading bytes from the `Inputstream` of a `Socket` (`socket.getInputStream()`) and at the end of the stream, a new `String` is created, with UTF-8 as the charset, which is then added to a `TextView`.

When encoded with UTF-8, the pound symbol shows up as '?'. However, when encoded with ISO-8859-1, the symbol shows up fine.

Is there a way to show the symbol correctly when using UTF-8?

Comment: Seems like your `Inputstream` is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`. Open a new file in `Gedit` (or whatever editor which allows reenconding at save), paste the stream, save it in `UTF-8` and feed it to your program, and test the result.

Comment: The Inputstream is from a socket, updated question to reflect this.

Comment: The character set parameter to the String constructor doesn't tell Java how to encode the string in memory, it tells it how to decode it from the byte array. You need to use the character set that the one you're receiving from the socket.

Comment: were you able to fix this issue for you ?